# What type of Exception will Enum.valueOf throw?

Tags: apex, enum, winter22

In Winter 22 we are getting a long desired (if somewhat niche) feature:

> #### [Use the valueOf() Enum Method to Convert a Specified String to an Enum Constant Value](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_valueOfMethod.htm&type=5&release=234)
>
> The valueOf() enum method converts a specified string to an enum constant value. An exception is thrown if the input string doesn’t match an enum value. In previous releases, using this method resulted in a runtime error.

What type of exception specifically is thrown?

Comment: P.S. You can get your own at [this sign up page](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter22/), and Scratch Orgs should support Winter 22 by this weekend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a `System.NoSuchElementException` in the prerelease edition of Winter '22, so that is likely what it will be in the release.

Comment: I'll raise a task to get the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_enum.htm) updated with the explicit exception name.